# Custom layout with WindowManager

Tags: android

For some reason, I keep getting an Error inflating Class message because I'm trying to implement

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at pap.crowslanding.GameView.(GameView.java:49)

Line 49 is this

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

I am doing it this way because I am not in an Activity, any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
static final long FPS = 10;
public Bitmap bmp;
public SurfaceHolder holder;
public LoopGameThread loopGameThread;
public static Sprite sprite;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

//maze variables
  public int width;                 
  public int height;
  private float cellWidth;
  private boolean[][] north;     // is there a wall to north of cell i, j
  private boolean[][] east;
  private boolean[][] south;
  private boolean[][] west;
  private boolean[][] visited;
  private double size;
  boolean done = false;

  Display display = new 
  Paint paint = new Paint();




//maze variables
   public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
   WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
   Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
   Point screenSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(screenSize);
    int width = screenSize.x;
    int height = screenSize.y;

}
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO
}

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);

    //maze variables
    initVars(attrs);
    initMaze();
    generate(1, 1);
    //maze variables
    loopGameThread = new LoopGameThread(this);
    holder = getHolder();

    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            loopGameThread.isStart(true);
            loopGameThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

    });

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.crow);
    sprite = new Sprite(this, bmp);

}


//MAZE VARIABLES

private void initVars(AttributeSet attrs) {
      //requires display variables
  }
```

Then within my initVars, I need to use those display variables

EDIT 2 :

```
package pap.crowslanding;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Game extends MainActivity{
static boolean pressedUp = false;
 protected static GameView gameV;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.tester1);


    Button moveLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    gameV = (GameView)findViewById(R.id.game_view);



    moveLeft.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private Handler mHandler;

        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mHandler != null) return true;
                mHandler = new Handler();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mAction, 100);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mHandler == null) return true;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAction);
                mHandler = null;
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        Runnable mAction = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                System.out.println("Performing action...");
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                GameView.sprite.movementGo();
            }
        };

    });
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you getting the `ctx` value from? It's a context value.... are you passing a context down from an Activity? We need to see more code.

Comment: I just created: public Context ctx; because I was not sure what to do with ctx and it required it. I could not find anything for it

Comment: Where is this function? What you just did is created a null Context, and that's exactly why it's giving you a null pointer. You need to get the Activity's context and pass it to this function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass your context down to whatever class is calling this function.

You could for example, keep local context value in your class which you can refer to in your functions. First, you'll need to make a constructor which will pass in a context to your class to use.

```
public class Example {
    Context mContext;

    public Example(Context mContext;){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public someFunction(){
        ...
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        ...
     }
}
```

In your Activity class that creates an instance of your class and uses it, you'll need to pass in the Activity's context like so:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Example test = new Example(this); //You are passing in the Activity as the context here
        test.someFunction();

    }
}
```

**EDIT to your edit:**

Create a new local variable in your GameView class:

```
private Context mContext;
```

Then assign a value to `mContext` in your GameView constructor like so:

```
 public GameView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      mContext = context;
      ...
  }
```

You can now use `mContext` inside of your `initVars()` function

Comment: I have edited my code to show you what I wanted to do, thanks

Comment: @RyanAlexander Your `public GameView(Context context)` has an instance of a `Context` pass to it. Create a local variable in your class file `mContext`, and in your constructor, assign `mContext = context`. You can then use `mContext` anywhere else in your code.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what context I need to pass through, I just want to use the display parameters

So I'm not sure what to write on my Activity. I have edited my page to show my activity which uses GameView as a context

Comment: I have applied your edit, but unfortunately this still provided me with a null pointer exception and i get the problem:

04-17 15:47:45.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22639):  at pap.crowslanding.GameView.initVars(GameView.java:110)
04-17 15:47:45.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22639):  at pap.crowslanding.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:67)